# Configuring hystrix thread pool for a system with high RPS and 99%ile response time ~500ms

Tags: hystrix

As per hystrix docs thread pool should be configured using below formula :

```
ThreadPoolSize = requests per second at peak when healthy × 99th percentile latency in seconds + some breathing room
```

We have an external service whose 99%ile response time is ~500ms and expected RPS is 200. so with the formulae the thread pool size comes out to be **100**. I don't think it is a good idea to configure thread pool with such a high number.

Please suggest what can be done in this scenario. What should be the ideal value for thread pool size and queue.